# counting null values in sql with where and group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Here is the sample data for test table I have

```
[childId] [parentId] [present]
1         10         0
2         11         1
3         NULL       0
4         NULL       0
NULL      10         0
```

Now, for all the parentIds (including those with NULL) I want to count all the present childIds

```
select parentId, count(childId) as nbr
from TestTable
where present=1 or parentId is NULL
group by parentId
```

The result I get is

```
parentId    nbr
NULL        2
11          1
```

Same count number (`nbr`) I get for both present=1 and present=0. It seems that I cannot impose a condition for the `NULL` grouped value.
What's the mistake I'm making and what's the solution for the query I want to make?

---

**UPDATE**:

Since the test case I gave is not representative, until I recreate the real situation in better way, I'll try to explain the problem I'm facing.

I created a view with full outer join, so I have some records having `NULL` for `childId` and some records having `NULL` for `parentId`.
Now, I want to list all of the `parentId` values (both `NULL` and non `NULL`) and for each of them, count all the records that, for example, have `present=1`.
If I use `where present=1` condition, it eliminates NULL values from result set, i.e. I won't have result record `NULL|x` for `parentId|nbr`.
 I solved this with `union all`. In first select I have `where present=1` and in second select I have `where present=1 and parentId is NULL`.

```
select parentId, count(childId) as nbr
from TestTable
where present=0
group by parentId

union all

select parentId, count(childId) as nbr
from TestTable
where present=0 and parentId is NULL
group by parentId
```

The result I get is

```
    [parentId]  [nbr]
    NULL        2
    10          1
    NULL        2
```

The only problem with this (besides duplicated record for `parentId=NULL`), is that if there are no records with `parentId=NULL` and `present=1`, in result I won't have record with `NULL | 0` for `parentId|nbr` and I want to list ALL parentIds, both `NULL` and not `NULL`.
So to sum it up I need to have this format of output for `present=1`

```
    [parentId]  [nbr]
    NULL        0
    10          0
    11          1
```

and this one for `present=0`

```
    [parentId]  [nbr]
    NULL        2
    10          2
    11          0
```

Any help?

Comment: if you just skip looking at is null, and say `SELECT parentid, COUNT(*) AS nbr FROM TestTable WHERE present = 1 GROUP BY parentid`, how do the results differ from what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the real situation I have with this test sample but it's now I see that I didn't give a right example and test data.

Comment: If you want to show the NULL Parent, and show wether they have a present 0 or 1, you just add the present column to your group by. See my updated answer

Comment: See updated answer based on your updated information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where present=1 or parentId is NULL
```

That would be it. Either you have Present = 1 or parentID is null. There's no clause saying that parentID should be null **and** present should be 1.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

To list all non-null parentID that has present = 1 and all null parentID regardless of present, you can use your where clause, but edit your group by to `GROUP BY parentid, present`. This way you will show all non-null with present 1, and all null, both present 0 and 1.

UPDATE:
Based on your new requirements, you need to also group for non-existing combinations. Nowhere in your dataset is there a NULL, 1 value - so your ordinary way of looking at it won't make much sense. You need to separate the parentid and present from eachother.

One way to do this is to simply do the following:

```
SELECT parentID, Pres1.nbr_pres_1, Pres0.nbr_pres_0
FROM t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(1) as nbr_pres_1 FROM t t1 WHERE 
             coalesce( t.parentid , -999) = coalesce(t1.parentid ,-999) and present=1 ) Pres1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(1) as nbr_pres_0 FROM t t0 WHERE 
             coalesce( t.parentid , -999) = coalesce(t0.parentid ,-999) and present=0 ) Pres0
GROUP BY t.ParentID, Pres1.nbr_pres_1, Pres0.nbr_pres_0
```

This is based on testing using sqlfiddle and your sample data set. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d7f6/29

Comment: I want to list all non-null parentIds with present=1 and all null parentIds with present=1. I accomplished this with union all. In first select I have `where present=1` and in second select I have `where present=1 and parentId is NULL`. The only problem with this, is that if there are no records with `parentId=NULL` and `present=1`, in result I won't have record with `NULL | 0` for `parentId|nbr` and I want to list ALL parentIds, both NULL and not NULL. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Use a SUM aggregation of the present field, casting the bit field to integer, as follows:

```
SELECT parentId, SUM(CAST(present AS INTEGER)) as nbr
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY parentId
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the result you are looking for:

```
pId    nbr
NULL   1
10     0
11     1
```

Then I think this is the sql you are looking for(not tested yet, no server available):

```
select distinct 
  parentId as pId, 
  (select count(*) from TestTable where parentId=pId and present=1) as nbr
from TestTable 
group by parentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned code snippet.

```
SELECT ParentId, COUNT(ChildId) nbr FROM SO
```

Where (Present = 1) OR (ParentId IS NULL AND Present = 1)
Group by ParentId

--OR You can try below mentioned code as well.

```
SELECT ParentId, COUNT(ChildId) nbr FROM SO
```

Where Present = 1
Group by ParentId